# Passing different values to the SELECT NEW part of a LINQ query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I am creating a result object from my query, something like this:

```
var result = from m in MyTable
             join r in some_more_tables
             select new ResultSummmary
             {
                  Description = m.Description,
                  start_date = r.start_dat
             };
```

But based on some condition before I get to this query and `SELECT NEW`, I want to be able to flex what I put in its `Description` filed, currently it is always `m.Description` but sometimes I want it to be a static text like "Hospital" and the rest of the times I want it to be `m.Description` as it is now.

How can we write it that way to be flexible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's pretend the condition is stored in a variable called `condition`.  This would allow you to write the following

```
var result = from m in MyTable
         join r in some_more_tables
         select new ResultSummmary
         {
              Description = condition ?  m.Description : "Hospital",
              start_date = r.start_dat
         };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select new ResultSummmary
             {
                  Description = someBool ? m.Description : "Hospital",
                  start_date = r.start_dat
             };
```